# Why does Windows credentials manager cache my log in credentials while using API in Excel vba to request data from JIRA server. How to disable this?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using VBA to make a request from Excel VBA to JIRA server, to get issues. In order to pull data from JIRA we have to provide log in credentials to the server with our username and password. when the file is opened for the first time and the "sub" is executed, it asks the user to enter their username and password, here's the catch in this instance when a user enters a wrong password and username the server is able to identify the credentials are wrong. then when the correct credentials are entered the application give a success response. now we test the sub again with wrong credentials, the server still acknowledges the request as valid. it seems that the credentials are getting cached and is using the same credentials to log in by "Windows Credential Manager". how do i tell the credentials manager to not cache the credentials ?

TL;DR

while testing the code i wrote for pulling data from jira server into excel file, the application asks the user to log in. for the first time it works correctly as in is able to identify the correct credentials and wrong credentials. but when a user log in with their correct credentials, no mater what credentials i give, it still uses the 1st correct credentials.

```
With http1
    .Open "GET", url1, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
    .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & user_name_password_in_base64_encoding
   
    'Send the HTTP request and retrieve the response
    .send ""
    End With
    If http1.Status <> 200 Then
    MsgBox "wrong credentials, try again with another vaild credentials" & http1.Status
    Exit Sub
    Else
    MsgBox "Log in success, retriving data"
    End If
    
    response1 = http1.responseText
```

this is the code, do i have to specify when the request is being made. Thank you.